# How to infinitely loop redstone detection with computercraft (lua)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I'm trying to make a harvester/planter out of computercraft computers, and I can get a redstone pulse consistent with a crop maturing, but cannot loop my command `redstone.getInput("front")` to keep checking without the program crashing.

```
-- Harvest Program
    --inf loop
while true do
    -- Redstatus is just a bool variable
    if RedStatus = redstone.getInput("front") then
    rednet.send(1, "shell.run("Harvest")")
end
```

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/BeZgShpY)      this is part of one (works)

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/3QMppy8a) This is the other part to this one (doesn't work)

Comment: is a lone `then` without a corresponding `end` allowed?

Comment: @Sumurai8 'then' and 'end' statements are not necessarily paired, 'if' and 'then' are, and also 'while true do' and 'end' are paired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `os.sleep(x)` at the end of your loop. The loop will then be executed every `x` seconds.